# knockout child objects on array have the value of last item

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am quite baffled as why even though my ingredients get populated correctly in the list and rendered, when I change the value of for example first ingredient's "Dosage Reference System" it then gets mixed up with the Dosage Reference System's value of the last item in the array?

The values in each row don't update according to the values in that row

Any help would be appreciated:

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/makeitmorehuman/C6AvC/

Code for reference here is:

```
function ingredient(data) {
        ingr = this;
        ingr.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        ingr.UnitCost = ko.observable(data.UnitCost);
        ingr.DRS = ko.observable(data.DRS);
        ingr.DP = ko.observable(data.DP);
        ingr.PercenChange = ko.computed(function () {
            return Math.round(ingr.DP() - ingr.DRS());
        });
        ingr.RawMaterialRS = ko.computed(function () {              
            return Math.round((ingr.DRS() / 100) * ingr.UnitCost() * 10000);
        });
        ingr.RawMaterialCostProp = ko.computed(function () {
            return Math.round((ingr.DP() / 100) * ingr.UnitCost() * 10000);
        });
        ingr.CostDifference = ko.computed(function () {
            return Math.round(ingr.RawMaterialCostProp() - ingr.RawMaterialRS());
        });
    }

    function ingredientsData() {
        return [
            { "Name": "Skimmed milk", "UnitCost": 0.40, "DRS": 70, "DP": 87 },
            { "Name": "Cream 40% fat", "UnitCost": 1.80, "DRS": 18, "DP": 9 },
            { "Name": "Skim Milk Powder", "UnitCost": 2.5, "DRS": 12, "DP": 1 },
            { "Name": "N-Dulge SAI", "UnitCost": 3.5, "DRS": 0, "DP": 2 },
            { "Name": "Novation Indulge 1720", "UnitCost": 3.9, "DRS": 0, "DP": 1 }
        ];
    }

    function NovationIndulge() {
        var self = this;

        self.Ingredients = ko.observableArray();

        self.init = function () {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(ingredientsData(), function (item) {
                self.Ingredients.push(new ingredient(item));
            });
        };

        function SumOfItems(propertyToSum) {
            var total = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Ingredients(), function (item) {
                total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(item[propertyToSum]());
            });
            return total;
        }

        self.TotalDRS = ko.computed(function () { return SumOfItems("DRS"); });
        self.TotalDP = ko.computed(function () { return SumOfItems("DP"); });
        self.TotalCostDiff = ko.computed(function () { return SumOfItems("CostDifference"); });
        self.TotalRawMaterialRS = ko.computed(function () { return SumOfItems("RawMaterialRS"); });
        self.TotalRawMCP = ko.computed(function () { return SumOfItems("RawMaterialCostProp") });

        self.AnnualFinishedProduct = ko.observable(4000);
        self.TotalCostSavingP1000 = ko.computed(function () { return self.TotalCostDiff() * -1 });
        self.TotalAnnualSaving = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.TotalCostSavingP1000() * self.AnnualFinishedProduct() / 1000;
        });
    }

    var NI = new NovationIndulge();
    NI.init();
    ko.applyBindings(NI);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that because you define

```
function ingredient(data) {
    ingr = this;
    ...
```

**without** the `var` keyword, it will instead create a global property (belonging to window).
Then, every time a function in your prototype runs, stuff is messed up.

Comment: I need you give the address to here you so guys can come and punch me a little

Comment: Hehe don't beat yourself up! Stuff happens. Closure is a blessing and a curse.

Answer (score 1):

This was a nice one. The offending line is this:

```
ingr = this;
```

should be

```
var ingr = this;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6nXYE/1/

Comment: is it ok if i give the tick to the boy with less reputation? that doesn't negate your right to punch me :)

Comment: Sure! About the punching, don't worry, this happens a lot to me too.